# Or operator for a regular expression in Google Analytics

Tags: regex, google-analytics

how can I change a regex of the funnels in order to test for urls? After a additional translation of a wordpress site english urls of woocommerce has changed.

https://regex101.com/r/HybY5q/2

```
.*/produkt/.*/
```

EN: http://www.example.com/en/product/1234 
DE: http://www.example.com/produkt/1234

```
.*/warenkorb/
```

EN: http://www.example.com/en/cart
DE: http://www.example.com/warenkorb

```
.*/kasse/
```

EN: http://www.example.com/en/checkout-2/
DE: http://www.example.com/kasse

As I don't want to change to URLs of Wordpress/WooCommerce how can I adjust the regular expressions? I think its an "OR" operator.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a or-operator (`|`) within a capturing group which will allow you to match the way you want to:

```
\/(warenkorb|cart)\/?
```

see [this in your updated example](https://regex101.com/r/HybY5q/5)

Also, i do not know google analytics that well, but within regular expressions, you usually have to escape tokens like `/` using `\` like you can see in the expression above. The example you provided didn't do that to and therefore didn't match.

Comment: No, `/` should only be escaped within `/` regex delimiters. GA regex does not use regex delimiters. [Original regex does not match](https://regex101.com/r/HybY5q/6) even with different delimiters.

Comment: Thanks. Great and simple. I thing that Google Analytics accepts "/" because URLs contains always / and Google wants to make it easier.

Does analytics accept this: 
\/(warenkorb|cart)\/?

Comment: like i said, i dont know ;) but glad i could help

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew good to know, I just used the settings provided in his sample which was JS, that why i noticed it had to be escaped. But good hint anyways

Comment: Google Analytics uses RE2 engine, not JS. No need for regex delimiters

Comment: Analytics has also a solution to test regex:

http://www.analyticsmarket.com/freetools/regex-tester